# kotlin - Problem with my if statement and operator

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin, operators

This is my goal : user click on minus button the amount decrease by one and there is a if statement to not allow the amount go lower than 0 .

This is my Code :

```
   var number = 0
        view.text_amount.visibility = View.GONE

        view.plus_btn.setOnClickListener {

            if (number == 5) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "Limit in order",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } else {
                view.text_amount.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                number++
                view.text_amount.text = number.toString()
            }
        }
        view.minus_btn.setOnClickListener {
            if (number <= 0) {
                view.text_amount.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                number--
                view.text_amount.text = number.toString()

            }

        }
```

there is problem with code : I don't want the amount be visible after getting to 0 . it's better experience when the amount is equal to 0 not be visible .

I think it has a simple solution but I can't see it .
do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decrease the value of `text_amount` only if it contains a value greater than `0` and after that check again its value and if it is `0` then hide it:

```
view.minus_btn.setOnClickListener {
    if (number > 0) {
        number--
        view.text_amount.text = number.toString()      
        if (number == 0) view.text_amount.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine! If you want to make it simpler, there's a bit of repeated logic you could condense into one function that handles the situations:

```
fun adjustValue(amount: Int) {
    val adjusted = number + amount
    if (adjusted > 5) // show Toast
    number = adjusted.coerceIn(0, 5)
    view.text_amount.text = number.toString()
    view.text_amount.visibility = if (number == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
}

view.minus_btn.setOnClickListener { adjustValue(-1) }
view.plus_btn.setOnClickListener { adjustValue(1) }
```

basically the idea is you work out the new value (I'm using a temporary variable so we never set `number` to an invalid value) and show whatever warnings you need to. Then the `coerceIn` line makes sure we lock it within the valid range of allowed values.

You could do `if/else` checks and only set the new value if it's a valid one, but sometimes it's simpler and shorter to just set things and then worry about the edge cases, so this is just an example of that!

Same thing for the `TextView` bit - it's easier to just set the value whatever it is, and then set whether it should be displayed or not. You could use `if/else` branches to look at the value and decide whether to set the text or not... but why make your life hard? We know the value's in the valid 0 to 5 range, we can hide it if it's 0 and show it otherwise... easy!

---

You could make the function take a `Boolean` instead, like `plus: Boolean` and then go `val adjusted = number + if (plus) 1 else -1`, but making it an `Int` means you could easily add a +10 button or whatever without adding any more code or any more validation logic, and it's not any more complicated to pass in `-1` instead of `false` (arguably it's clearer!)

that's probably more than you were asking for but hopefully it's useful. If nothing else, the "just set the text and the visibility every time" approach is good and neat